# What tools allow for creation and editing of a PDF document on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, leopard

I would like to create a PDF document with images, text and table of contents.
I have also other PDF documents that I would like to merge in this new PDF.

Do you know some tools/software for creating PDFs?

Comment: Consider re-titling. You already have PDFs, so it isn't creating it from scratch. Also, if you are OK with a (La)TeX solution, you'll get a more detailed answer on http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Clickable or just-text TOC?

Comment: @mankoff Clickable

Comment: i think you'll want to use (La)TeX and re-post this question on the appropriate site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Adobe InDesign for this kind of thing... more flexible than AcrobatPro. Allows total control over what you import into the pdf (text,images, other pdfs, etc.) and the ability to create clickable TOCs. If you are going to do a lot of this, or a lot of print, it is worth the investment.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually merge multiple PDFs right from Preview.app. Just open two PDFs in two separate windows, turn on the sidebars, and drag pages from one sidebar to the other. This won't provide you with a table of contents, but you can always just make something in TextEdit, export it as a PDF, then add it to the beginning of the document.

Comment: Table of contents should be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFPen](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/index.html) and [PDFPenPro](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpenPro/index.html) from Smile Software have many capabilities and are quite affordable.

Comment: +2 if I could - some of my favorite software for PDF wrangling.

Answer (score 0):

fast free way:

1. Print each file as PDF:

File->Print->save as PDF

1. Use this free utility to merge PDF's to one PDF file

http://lifehacker.com/279571/merge-multiple-pdfs-with-combine-pdfs-21

Otherwise use Adobe Pro for Mac

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Word 2011 does a solid job of creating content and saving to PDF.

File > Save As then change Format to PDF.