# Mac app for editing PDF documents

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best reader for annotating PDFs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7667/best-reader-for-annotating-pdfs)

I am looking for a simple app (ideally free) for OSX that allows you to edit PDF documents, essentially providing you with the ability to add text onto a PDF document, save or print it. Similar to http://www.pdfescape.com but as an app. Does something like this exist?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but have a look at [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). It's a command-line program.

Comment: Maybe you should try Preview ob MacOS Mountain Lion?

Comment: We have some good coverage already on tools that edit, alter and annotate PDF. How do these differ from your question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/how-to-create-a-pdf-document http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/what-software-is-available-preferably-free-to-create-and-edit-pdf-files-on-mac